# 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable Nginx + Kibana + AKS

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, azure-aks, kibana-7

I have deployed Kibana in AKS with the server.basepath of `/logs` since I want it to be deployed in subpath. I am trying to access Kibana service using nginx controller It is giving 503 service unavailable but Service/Pod is running. Please help me on this.

Kibana Deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kibana
  namespace: kube-logging
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: kibana
    helm.sh/chart: kibana-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: icy-coral
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Tiller
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: kibana
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: icy-coral
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: kibana
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: icy-coral
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: kibana
          image: "docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.6.0"
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 5601
              protocol: TCP
          env:
            - name: ELASTICSEARCH_URL
              value: http://elasticsearch:9200
            - name: SERVER_BASEPATH
              value: /logs
            - name: SERVER_REWRITEBASEPATH
              value: "true"
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 1000m
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
```

Kibana service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kibana
  namespace: kube-logging
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: kibana
    helm.sh/chart: kibana-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: icy-coral
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Tiller
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 5601
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: kibana
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: icy-coral
```

Kibana Ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kibana
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: kibana
    helm.sh/chart: kibana-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: icy-coral
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Tiller
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/send-timeout: "600"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "1800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "1800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"

spec:
  rules:
    - host: ""
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /logs/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: kibana
              servicePort: 80
```

Comment: this path is `/logs/`, not `/logs`?

Comment: when I do port forwarding, then it is working

"$ kubectl port-forward svc/kibana 5601:80 -n kube-logging"

http://localhost:5601/logs/app/kibana#/home

But it is not working only with nginx ingress

Comment: Does the same happen when you change kibana service type to `NodePort`?

Comment: Yes, It is same.

Comment: Is your elascricsearch pod running? When you port-forward kibana can you access it on localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure kibana is running with:

`kubectl logs kibana`

Check the endpoint for the service is not empty:

`kubectl describe svc kibana`

Check the ingress is correctly configured:

`kubectl describe ingress kibana`

check the ingress-controller logs:

`kubectl logs -n nginx-ingress-controller-.....`

**Update:**

You can only refer services on the same namespace of the ingress. So try to move ingress to `kube-logging` namespace.

Checkout this: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/17088

Comment: I checked that pod is running and I am able to connect to that service using port forwarding. But it is not working only with Nginx Ingress.

Comment: I did move ingress to same namespace ("kube-logging") still it not working.